# Renaming columns based on condition about their names

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I would like to add a prefix to my dataset column names only if they already begin with a certain string, and I would like to do it (if possible) using a `dplyr` pipeline.

Taking the `iris` dataset as toy example, I was able to get the expected result with base R (with a quite cumbersome line of code):

```
data("iris")
colnames(iris)[startsWith(colnames(iris), "Sepal")] <- paste0("YAY_", colnames(iris)[startsWith(colnames(iris), "Sepal")])
head(iris)
  YAY_Sepal.Length YAY_Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1              5.1             3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2              4.9             3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3              4.7             3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4              4.6             3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5              5.0             3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6              5.4             3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

In this example, the prefix `YAY_` has been added to all the column names starting with `Sepal`. Is there a way to obtain the same result with a `dplyr` command/pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be `rename_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
   rename_at(vars(starts_with("Sepal")), ~ str_c("YAY_", .)) 
#   YAY_Sepal.Length YAY_Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1              5.1             3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2              4.9             3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3              4.7             3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4              4.6             3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5              5.0             3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6              5.4             3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# ...
```

Comment: I didn't know that also `rename` and `select` had their scoped variants, I didn't think about it, my bad. Another small question: why is there the tilde before `str_c`?

Comment: @RicS  The anonymous function convention with `tidyverse` use `~` otherwise, you can use `function(x) x`

Comment: Two birds with a stone, it's always nice when I learn two concepts with a single question. Thank you for your help!